# Вопрос по MYSQL , правильная выборка

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день, есть проблема с выборкой данных из MYSQL. Пишу сайт для рейтинга, компаний и наткнулся на подобную проблему.

О проблеме:
   Есть 2 таблицы. 2 - companys а вторая fileds

Таблица companys - имеет столбцы из которых нам нужен лишь id
   Таблица fileds -   имеет столбцы comp_id,rating

Каждая компания имеет 5 полей опроса в fileds и привязана к companys(Компании).

Есть запрос MYSQL где JOIN-ом вывожу данные из 2-вух таблиц, нужно получить не 5 результатов от каждой компании, а общую суму rating 5 полей под одним id.

Пример Запроса без суммирования:

```
SELECT client.companys.id, client.fileds.rating FROM client.companys INNER JOIN client.fileds ON 
client.companys.id = client.fileds.comp_id
Order by rating desc
```

И скрин прикрепляю результата.[image: результат запроса]

Comment: Не понятно зачем в запросе вообще нужна таблица companys, если нужен только id, который и так есть в fields. `select comp_id, sum(rating)  from fields group by comp_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  client.companys.id,
  SUM(client.fileds.rating) AS rating
FROM
  client.companys
INNER JOIN
  client.fileds
ON 
  client.companys.id = client.fileds.comp_id
GROUP BY
  client.companys.id
ORDER BY
  rating DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо сработало.